# Linux scheduler behaviour on memory shortage

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, out-of-memory, scheduler

I have two programs.

This is the first:

```cpp
#include<iostream>
#include<chrono>
#include<ctime>
int main()
{
    int x=1;
    auto t=std::chrono::system_clock::now();
    while(true)
    {
        for(long i=0;i<(long)1<<27;i++)
            x*=2;
        auto t2=std::chrono::system_clock::now();
        std::cout<<(t2-t).count()/1000000<<std::endl;
        t=t2;
    }
}
```

It does a lot of computation in the for-loop and logs the time elapsed in milliseconds after each run of the loop.

This is the second:

```cpp
#define L 256*1024*1024
int main()
{
    while(1)
    {
        char *c=new char[L];
        for(long i=0;i<L;i++)
            c[i]='a';
    }
    return 0;
}
```

It repeatedly allocates a lot of memory, until finally getting killed after some time.

I ran the first program as a background job and then started the second.
This was the terminal output:

```
229
230
232
232
232
235
300
658
Killed
271
229
228
230
228
224
224
223
229
```

As we can see, the time taken for each for-loop was normally around 230 ms but it went upto 658 ms when the second process was killed because of memory shortage. There is no swap memory in my system.

My question is that why does this happen? There are 6 CPU cores, so why does the first process slow down due to the second?

My first guess was that the first process may be needing memory. But then I thought that the terminal buffer is fixed size, so write to stdout must not require memory. And later, I even wrote a program which does not print to stdout, and there also the same phenomenon was observed.

I would be thankful if somebody could explain exactly why this happens.

Answer (score 0):

The Linux kernel maintains a run queue for each scheduling class and CPU core so in your case the total run queues will be: 6 * 5 = 30. 6 cores and 5 scheduling classes. At any given moment of time a single process will be on one run queue. so your programs in theory will only cross each other if they are both at same run queue(assuming you set the CPU affinity of your programs to same core using system call `SCHED_SETAFFINITY`)

---

But this is just what is supposed to happen. Linux kernel is a fully preemptive kernel which means it will preempt whatever is running if there is has higher priority process that needs to run like a real time process of scheduling policy `SCHED_FIFO` OR `SCHED_RR`. Also hardware interrupts always have higher priority so they will interrupt your programs if they arrive to the core.

In summery, This test doesn't show anything since you didn't check if both are running on different cores in addition to hardware interrupts are still enabled so they can preempt your current programs.

---

Finally, please note that even you made sure that both are on different cores with disabled hardware interrupts there will still be inconsistency in your timing since today CPU's implement different measures to improve performance like pipelining and out-of-order execution that will make your measurements non representative to some extent.

---

**Regarding Your comment:**
In your example you keep allocating memory until the OOM killer get's invoked. You can verify by running `dmesg | grep -i oom`. This will cause your memory allocating process to be killed. This is when your first process time increased. The OOM killer got invoked. And for the second time timing these kind of things can be very difficult on SMP os and today's CPU's.

Comment: Thanks, but hardware interrupts are needed for preemption. So, how can I disable them? My question was that the first process is running okay even when the second process is started as there is enough RAM available. But gradually, as the second process fills up the RAM, the first process slows down, reaching a peak until the second process is killed. So what is happening at that time that the first process is slowed down?

Comment: @UjjwalRajput read the last paragraph. I edited the answer.